# After calling function I'm getting error saying undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my table 1st column has a tags with href's and 3rd column has some text. So, I want to save all href's into an array where their respective 3rd column matches some string and use it for later purpose. I had tried the following code nothing seems wrong to me, can some one assist me with this.

```js
function findimagelinks(){
    var rows = jQuery(".sortable tr.even").length + jQuery(".sortable tr.odd").length;
    var imglinks = [];
    
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
        var conditionvalue =jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(i+1) td:eq(3)").text();
        if(conditionvalue == "some string"){
            imglinks[i] = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(i+1) td:eq(0) a").attr('href');
        }
    }
    console.log(imglinks);
}

findimagelinks();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. Properly concatenate the strings like this

```
var conditionvalue = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(3)").text();
```

Then your code will look like,

```
 for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     var conditionvalue = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(3)").text();
     if (conditionvalue == "some string") {
         imglinks[i] = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(0) a").attr('href');
     }
 }
```

Comment: @ravishankardivvela atleast consiider the time of posting. This is the first answer..

Comment: I did check it he was 1 min earlier.

Comment: @ravishankardivvela just hover on the time, his time is "2015-06-19 11:13:17Z",  and mine is "2015-06-19 11:11:55Z" which is 2 minutes before..

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation is not right!

```
var conditionvalue = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(3)").text();
// ------------------------------------------^

imglinks[i] = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(0) a").attr('href');
// -----------------------------------^
```

**Updated Snippet**

```js
function findimagelinks(){
  var rows = jQuery(".sortable tr.even").length + jQuery(".sortable tr.odd").length;
  var imglinks = [];

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var conditionvalue = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(3)").text();
    if (conditionvalue == "some string") {
      imglinks[i] = jQuery(".sortable tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ") td:eq(0) a").attr('href');
    }
  }
  console.log(imglinks);
}

findimagelinks();
```

Comment: Sorry my bad thank for the reply. There is one more thing, So according to above code top 4 rows are not getting saved into array and bottom four are saved into array. According to that key value in array is starting from 4 not 1 is there any way i can get key value started at "1".